# Optimizing quadrilateral construction from coordinates

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization, graph, mathematical-optimization

Here's the problem to be solved:

> Given four vertices, find four edges between each coordinates such that they form a quadrilateral.

Since none of the edge in the quadrilateral can cross any other edges, I would just pick an edge from two random vertices, and check if the edge crosses the edge from two remaining vertices.

Here's a rough implementation of it:

```
import random
import numpy as np


# Line segment intersection algorithm - created by Bryce Boe
# Source - http://bryceboe.com/2006/10/23/line-segment-intersection-algorithm/
# edge AB and CD won't intersect if this returns false
def intersect(A, B, C, D):
return ccw(A,C,D) != ccw(B,C,D) and ccw(A,B,C) != ccw(A,B,D)


def ccw(A, B, C):
    return (C.y-A.y)*(B.x-A.x) > (B.y-A.y)*(C.x-A.x)


class Coord:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __str__(self):
        return "(%s,%s)" % (self.x, self.y)


# Choose an edge from two random vertices (and another edge from the two remaining vertices)
# Choose another set of two vertices until the two edges created don't intersect
def draw_quad(coords):
    if len(coords) != 4:
        raise AttributeError
    line_intersects = True
    while line_intersects:
        a, b = random.sample(coords, 2)
        c, d = [x for x in coords if x != a and x != b]
        line_intersects = not intersect(a, b, c, d)
    return [Coord(a, c), Coord(c, b), Coord(b, d), Coord(d, a)]
```

This solution, however, has 33% chance of picking vertices that fails the `intersect(a, b, c, d)` (given any coordinate, you have 2 nodes that results in non-intersecting edges, and 1 that does result in intersection), which requires additional iteration of the loop.

I do have another solution which uses polar coordinates to find the two pair of adjacent vertices (by avoiding the furthest vertice from a given vertice), but the solution is actually slower, since it requires far more computation.

Are there any different solution that are faster and guarantees a success on the first iteration?

Comment: Is your implementation too slow? If so, how do you know this? If not, why are you trying to optimize it?

Comment: @martineau I cannot make comparisons in terms of speed since there doesn't seem to be other examples available. The snippet of code above is made as a part of self-studying for algorithm optimization.

Comment: @Caladbolgll: What martineau is asking, more explicitly, is whether this is worth thinking about. It's often the case that the code we _think_ is slow is not, in fact, really the problem at all. For instance, perhaps this function is only called twice in a big program, in that case you'll get more significant gains out of optimizing hotspots elsewhere.

Comment: However, @martineau, I think this is a very interesting problem from an academic perspective, irrespective of whether it is a hotspot.

Comment: There is also the issue that you seem to be writing your could in Python. As an interpreted language, what seems best may be slowest and what is fastest may not be at all intuitive. Are you interested in the fastest algorithm to do this, or the fastest Python implementation?

Comment: @Richard I see what you're saying. This snippet isn't used with a significant frequency on the program I'm using, so I guess it is not a topic worth the discussion for a practical reason.

Comment: @Richard Although slightly out of topic, it may become more significant amount of computations if I was to generalize the algorithm to construct polygon from N vertices.

Comment: In that case, perhaps you should remove the the "python" tag and replace it with "computational-geometry". From that point-of-view, what's begin done is you're trying to (quickly) find how to construct a [**convex-polygon**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_polygon) out of the points.

Answer (score 0):

I propose another algorithm:

1. make a triangle of the first three points. Sides a1, a2, a3 and opposite them points A1, A2, A3.
2. For every side ai(i=1,2,3), try if the fourth point X is to the other side of ai than point Ai.
3. If the check is true, erase the side ai and draw two new ones from X to its ends. 
   Edit (Thanks to @dmuir)
4. If all checks fails, that mean that the fourth point is inside the triangle. Take a1, a2, a3, x for the quadrilateral.

Every such check is trivial. No randoms, no intersects.

Comment: What do you do if all checks in 2. fail, for example if the first three points are an equilateral triangle and the fourth point is the centre of the tiangle.